# SPARQL: How to get all triples with certain predicate where only one direction exists

Tags: sparql

I want to query all triples with a certain predicate p. The query should only return triples (s,p,o) where the other direction (o,p,s) does not exist.
How can I make such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o {
    ?s ?p ?o
    MINUS { ?o ?p ?s }
}
```

`FILTER NOT EXISTS` instead of `MINUS` would also work. Replace `?p` in the query with the desired predicate, or use something like `FILTER (?p=ex:myPredicate)` if you want `?p` in the result.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to directly add (o,p,s) in that case?

Comment: I don’t understand the question, can you explain?

Comment: If I (s,p,o) exists but (o,p,s) does not, then I want to add (o,p,s) to the graph. Of course p is fixed again.

Comment: I see. Something like `CONSTRUCT { ?o :p ?s } WHERE { ?s :p ?o MINUS { ?o :p ?s } }`?